# How to change this data input type in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this line in my programme-

```
num = int(input("Enter a number: "))
```

Now as the input type is int, I cannot use any exponents. How can I change the data input type from int to something else so that I can input exponents like `2**4` (= 2^4)?

Comment: You will need a parser that understands such input. What inputs do you want to accept?

Comment: you can get your input as a string, and then split it according to your need

Comment: If you only want to accept an expression that is the power of two numbers, you can split input on `**`.

Answer (score 4):

Don't use int() :)

```
>>> x = input("Enter a number:")
Enter a number:2**3
>>> print x
8
```

It can be explained by the documentation (https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input):

> ```
> input([prompt])
> ```
>
> Equivalent to `eval(raw_input(prompt))`.
>
> This function does not catch user errors. If the input is not syntactically valid, a SyntaxError will be raised. `Other exceptions may be raised if there is an error during evaluation.`
>
> ...
>
> Consider using the raw_input() function for general input from users.

In **python3** things a bit changed, so the following alternative will work:

```
x = eval(input("Enter a value"))
print(x)
```

Comment: Of course. That's how input works. Probably you thought about raw_input()?

Comment: Beware that this changed in Python 3.

Answer (score 0):

You could always accept a string and then split in on a delimiter of your choice, either ^ or **.

If I'm not mistaken, eval is insecure and should not be used (please correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: how insecure, can you explain a bit?

Comment: consider what will happen on you eval os.system("rm -rf /") .
If you'd like to get more information on the matter, please go to:

http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html

Hope this helps, friend.